Unable to find REST API documentation for Azure Bot Service [List by subscription]
I'm currently in search of the Azure REST API documentation, specifically for Azure Bot Services. I'm interested in finding the endpoint for List resources by subscription, within the [Microsoft.BotService/botServices] namespace. Despite my best efforts, I haven't been able to locate the relevant documentation. (REST API docs similar to this)
Could someone kindly confirm if this documentation exists and, if so, point me in the right direction to find it? Alternatively, if it's been deprecated or archived, clarity on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you all in advance!
I've tried to search Azure Bot Services in the Azure REST API docs (even under the AI services dropdown). I haven't been able to locate the documentation. I expect a documentation similar to this


Azure Bot Service: List by Subscription

To get the list by subscription of Azure Bot Service using the REST API, you can use the request below.
Request:
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices?api-version=2021-03-01
Header: 
   Authorization: <Bearer token>

Output:


Note: I couldn't find any documentation either. I just referred to the Azure Bot Service Python SDK Documentation.

Reference:
azure-sdk-for-python/sdk/botservice/azure-mgmt-botservice/generated_samples/list_bots_by_subscription.py at azure-mgmt-botservice_2.0.0 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-python · GitHub
